# Regex activate multi line in php

Tags: php, regex

Please tell me how to activate multi line functionality..and explain me how it work. (?m) or /m ?

```
$subject = "the brown fox jump bla
over the Lazy 
dog ..Bla bla bla";
$matching = preg_match_all($regex1, $subject, $m);
$regex1 = '(?m)/^bla$\b/i';
print_r($m);
```

what to use and where? ...(?m) or /m ?

Answer (score 2):

> what to use and where? ...(?m) or /m

You can use either of them but you cannot use `\b` (word boundary) after anchor `$`. So use:

```
$regex1 = '/^bla$/im';

$subject = "the brown fox jump bla
over the Lazy 
dog ..Bla bla bla";

preg_match_all($regex1, $subject, $m);
print_r($m);
```

**And you need to declare regex before you can use it.**

However none of you lines have just the text `bla` hence your regex will fail to match anything.

Looking at your examples you may probably need:

```
$regex1 = '/\bbla$/im';
```

which will match line #1 and line #3.

Comment: it find me 1 ocurrence of bla with $regex1 = '/\bbla$/im'; and if i delete m nothing happen the result is the same..why? what is the funtionality of /m(multi line)..Please give an sugestive example.

Comment: [See this demo](https://regex101.com/r/iW6wY0/2) and them remove `m` flag to see it not matching anything. It is happening due to use of `$` in regex which won't work without `m` flag.

Comment: By default, in all major engines, the anchors `^` and `$` only match (respectively) at the beginning and the end of the string. **multi-line** mode allows the anchors to operate on multiple lines.

Comment: Thanks! online working but in my editor sublime not working with /gm..and with /m find 1 occurrence of bla.

Comment: You question is about php code and demo I provide to you is also for PHP. You can ask a different question if you have a sublime question after marking this one as accepted.

Comment: If this answer helped you then you may mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.